# Are $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] $ isomorphic as Z modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Are $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] $ isomorphic as Z modules? I already know they are isomorphic as rings because $x^2+2$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{-2}$ However, I'm unable to write a module homomorphism between the two to verify if they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Thank you.

Comment: A $\Bbb Z$-module is just an abelian group. Then it is true.

Comment: Any isomorphism of rings is an isomorphism of abelian groups in particular.

Comment: Yes, i know Z-Modules are abelian groups. But how does this imply that it is true? @Watson

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right !!!!! Thank you all

Comment: An isomorphism of rings $R \to S$ induces an isomorphism $R^+ \to S^+$ of their underlying (additive) groups, and a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is just an abelian group.

Answer (score 3):

A $\Bbb Z$-module is just an abelian group.

Since your two rings are isomorphic as rings, in particular the underlying additive groups are isomorphic (as abelian groups, i.e. as $\Bbb Z$-modules). Your ring isomorphism is then a $\Bbb Z$-modules isomorphism.